# Why can't negative charge on a carbon have resonance with a neighboring alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

[image]

In these resonance forms of a conjugate base of ascorbic acid, why can't the electrons on the negatively charged carbon in the third form be used to form a double bond with the alcohol and thus delocalize the negative charge over the oxygen?

Comment: Because octet rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically, if the electrons on the negatively charged carbon in the third form be used to form a double bond with $\ce{O}$ of the $\ce{-OH}$ group, it would have made ten $\ce{e-}$s around that $\ce{O}$. That would violate the octet rule because $\ce{O}$ is a second raw element, and hence, no $3d$ orbitals to accommodate extra pair of $\ce{e-}$s.

That's been said, one would question whether these resonance forms are even possible because it is impossible to form a negative charge on $\ce{2C-OH}$ group (the second form) without forming a negative charge on $\ce{3C-OH}$ group at first. This is because, $K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{3C-OH}$ in ascorbic acid is $6.7\times 10^{-5}$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=4.17$), due to the conjugation through $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated carbonyl function, giving ascorbic acid an organic acid status. Note also that $\ce{2C-OH}$ is also fairly acitic with $K_\mathrm{a}$ of $2.5\times 10^{-12}$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=11.6$) because it is also an enol function. Nonetheless, in free ascorbic acid under basic conditions, $\ce{3C-OH}$ ionizes first before $\ce{2C-OH}$.

**Interesting fact:** Ascorbic acid is one of unique organic acids, which have no $\ce{-COOH}$ group. Two other notable examples are picric acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=0.3$) and squaric acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}=1.5$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}=3.5$). All of them are more acetic than benzoic acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=4.20$).